# PostGIS inserting shapefile with shp2pgsql, wrong coordinate system?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, shp2pgsql

I'm trying to load a shapefile ([link](https://statbel.fgov.be/fr/open-data/secteurs-statistiques))  into my database with shp2pgsql.

```
shp2pgsql -D -W UTF8 -I -s 4326 scbel01012011_gen13.shp bel | psql -d stat
```

no problem so far, but when I'm trying to get some informations from the table by using a coordinate I get no results.
I checked the table, all data are loaded. 
Here my query:

```
SELECT * FROM bel WHERE ST_Intersects(geom,ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(4.380286, 51.112025), 4326));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `-s 4326` you are overriding the SRS of the shapefile rather than reprojecting it. You want to use `-s 31370:4326` to force the reprojection of the data. So your entire command line becomes (since you can't use `-D` and reproject):

```
shp2pgsql -W UTF8 -I -s 31370:4326 scbel01012011_gen13.shp bel | psql -d stat
```

and your query returns one row:

```
15;17;"11001A20-";11001;"A20-";"11001A20-";"11001A20-";"11001A20-";"DE KOEKOEK"
```